# Making selected item bold in navigation drawer, but can't get the first item to be bold when the app starts

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to make the selected item's text bold in the navigation drawer (like Google Play apps), but I can't get the first item to be bold when first starting the app
This is what I'm using to make it work

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            setNavDrawerItemNormal();
            TextView TV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            TV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    public void setNavDrawerItemNormal() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mDrawerList.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = mDrawerList.getChildAt(i);
            TextView TV = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1));
            TV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
    }
```

I tried adding this in the `onCreate()` method, but it throws an error because of the second line

```
View view = mDrawerList.getChildAt(0);
TextView TV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
TV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

The LogCat says the it's caused by `java.lang.NullPointerException`
Any idea why this is happening? And how to make it work?

Comment: hope you didn't add those lines before setContentView, and that drawerList was initialized properly. Also, try setting the TypeFace in drawer adapter so it'l be called without an onClick event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because `mDrawerList.getChildAt(0)` returns the first **visible** child, not the first item in the list.

You may want to achieve your result in the getView() method of your adapter class:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...

    if(position == 0) {
        // set bold text here
    }

    ...
}
```